# not able to save data in mongo db using save method

Tags: mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error:'));

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        index:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    },
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    name:{
        type:String
    }
});

var User  = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
//code getting used to save data
// Accessing this code from user.js file , new user is getting printed                  
//but data is not getting saved in db.  
var createUser = function(newUser,callback){
    console.log(newUser);
    newUser.save(callback);
};

module.exports = {
    User,
    createUser
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this step:
1. just export User 
2. require User where you want to invoke save function;
3. try to call this code:

```
var newUser = new User({})
newUser.email = 'simon@theholmesoffice.com',
newUser.username='replace with username',
newUser.password ='replace with password',
newUser.name='replace with name'
newUser.save( function( err, user ){
if(!err){
console.log('_id of saved user: ' + user._id);
}
});
```